# Splitting an inputted string by comma and space

Tags: java, arrays, string, input, split

```
        while(scan.hasNext()){
        String line = scan.next();
        String[] tempArray = line.split(",\\s*");

        for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
            System.out.println(tempArray[i]);
        }
```

My input file looks like:

```
A, 0, 3 
C, 2, 2 
BB, 3, 3 
DA, -3, 0 
ED, 2, -2
```

It returns A, then gives me an error. What gives?

Comment: Out of bounds exception: 1, at the System.out.println(tempArray[i]); line

Comment: try using `scan.nextLine()`  and `line.split (",")`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a String in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split on comma and then `trim()` the `String`,

```
while(scan.hasNextLine()){                   // <-- hasNextLine()
  String line = scan.nextLine();             // <-- nextLine()
  String[] tempArray = line.split(",");      // <-- split on the comma.

  for (int i=0; i<tempArray.length; i++){    // <-- use the array length
    System.out.println(tempArray[i].trim()); // <-- trim() the String
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String line = scan.next();
```

For your input file, the first time you access this, `line` will be equal to `"A,"`, which is not what you wanted.

This is because `Scanner#next()` only reads up until a whitespace character, which is present in the input file between `A,` and `0,`. Hence, why only `A,` is returned.

Instead use

```
String line = scan.nextLine();
```

Which will read up until a line break. So the first loop will set `line` to `"A, 0, 3"`.

---

Debugging can really help improve programming abilities. Printing out the return of `line` to see what is being processed could have definitely helped with this. Being able to then figure out what is happening to produce those results is a lot easier.